# Is there any Risk to Reallocating an account size

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust

I was working on some code today, and I noticed that I couldn't reallocate an account by a difference of morethan 10KB. I reckon that I could do multiple reallocs to achieve any desired size, but given that per realloc, there is already a set limit, I am wondering whether it is a safe habit to do multiple reallocs, and why there is even the 10KB limit to start with.

thanks

```
         /// Maximum number of bytes a program may add to an account during a 
        single realloc
        pub const MAX_PERMITTED_DATA_INCREASE: usize = 1_024 * 10;

        // Return early if the length increase from the original serialized data
        // length is too large and would result in an out of bounds allocation.
        let original_data_len = unsafe { self.original_data_len() };
        if new_len.saturating_sub(original_data_len) > MAX_PERMITTED_DATA_INCREASE {
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidRealloc);
        }
```

the code excerpt is a mixture of slivers of the Solana program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe to perform multiple reallocs.  The per-tranasction limit is to rate-limit cluster-wide storage growth do a reasonable rate